# android : is it possible to user cursorloader with GreenDao

Tags: android, greendao, android-cursorloader

I use GreenDao in my app. Due to the size of the data, i want to use cursorloader to take care of pagination. How do i give the uri for CursorLoader if i am using GreenDao . I couldn't find any sample or any usage on my search. Is this possible with GreenDao

Comment: http://greenrobot.org/files/greendao/javadoc/2.1/de/greenrobot/dao/query/QueryBuilder.html#buildCursor()

Comment: could you please elaborate on your comment. I dont see any Uri in that link

Comment: the `buildCursor()` method returns `CursorQuery` object which has `query()` method that returns `android.database.Cursor` - use that `Cursor` in your custom `ContentProvider` (when using `CursorLoader`) or custom `AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>`

Comment: new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
            CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
 I wanted to know see any sample for baseUri in this case if using GreenDao